# How did Crystal get her gag off?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hunt-2020

In the early scenes of the heavily ironic and satirical movie [The Hunt](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8244784/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), a group of "deplorables" wake up in a field wearing gags in their mouths. They are to be hunted by a group of "liberal elites" they have (apparently) offended with their redneck, right wing, conspiracist views (which have specifically created hate against the group of "liberals".)

In the early scenes the group of deplorables find each other and a stash of guns. We see one of the deplorables find a key that unlocks the gags. But Crystal has chosen not to join with the group and leaves the scene *before* the key is found and the others unlock the gags.

The next time we see Crystal, she has removed her gag (which we see is not at all easy for the others without a key).

Is this a plot hole? How did Crystal remove her gag?

Answer (score 4):

I was also confused by the first scene in which we see Crystal (a.k.a. "Snowball"): One of the other prey women, also still gagged, sees Crystal from across a pond.  We see Crystal do the following:

1. Produce from her clothes a nametag that says "Crystal"
2. Break the pin off the clasp on the back of the nametag
3. With the pin in her hand, reach behind her head and through her hair, making something click.  Since this is the location of the small gag padlock on all of the other prey, I think we are supposed to conclude that **she used the pin to release the lock**.

---

The fact that Crystal silently ignores the other woman is strange, as is what she does before heading off in another direction: Crystal places a large leaf in the water and the places the pin on the leaf.  I surmise that Crystal is thinking something along the lines:

> I've been drugged, kidnapped, and gagged and I don't know where I am.  I don't know who that other woman is; maybe the same thing happened to her, or maybe she's in on whatever is going on.  If she's a victim then I've left her the tool I used to unlock the gag, but I'm stepping away until I get my bearings.

Comment: I too assumed when watching this that the point of breaking the pin from the badge was to pick the lock. But rewatching, this is *not* the prime purpose. She uses the pin as a compass to get her bearings (that's the floating on a leaf bit). But she is still clearly wearing the gag *after* using the pin as a compass as she walks away. Why open the lock and leave the gag on? Also, though, what is she doing rubbing it in her hair? It looks like we are *supposed* to think she is magnetising it (but that isn't physics).

Comment: "*reach behind her head and through her hair, making something click*" I just rewatched the scene with headphones on and I can't hear the "making something click" part. She was also not shown to be lockpicking, but rubbing the pin on her hair (to [magnetize the pin and use it as a compass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUIvcpLrkpQ)). When she left, the gag was still on her.